# How to create CosmosDB SQL API serverless account with ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create a serverless account with Cosmosdb sql api and i have not found any samples given [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.documentdb)

I have tried with the following ARM template and it's not creating a serverless account

```
  "resources" : [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01",
            "kind": "Serverless",
            "name": "[parameters('accountName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
              "enableFreeTier": false,            
              "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
              "consistencyPolicy": {
                "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Session"
              },
              "locations": [
                {
                  "locationName": "[parameters('location')]"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases",
            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01",
            "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('accountName'), parameters('databaseName'))]",
            "properties": {
              "resource": {
                "id": "[parameters('databaseName')]"
              },
              "options": {}
            },
            "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', parameters('accountName'))]"
            ]
          }

    ]
```

throwing an error "
**"message": "Resource kind Serverless is unknown\r\nActivityId: 0c86f162-3386-49e1-b354-57ba309bb44f, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0""**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is valid, below are the possible values available for the **`databaseAccount`** [kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts?tabs=bicep#databaseaccounts)

- 'GlobalDocumentDB'
- 'MongoDB'
- 'Parse'

To create a serverless account, you need to pass the capabilities parameter as below under properties

```
 "properties": {
          "enableFreeTier": false,
          "capabilities": [
            {
              "name": "EnableServerless"
            }
          ],
          "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
          "consistencyPolicy": {
            "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Session"
          },
          "locations": [
            {
              "locationName": "[parameters('location')]"
            }
          ]
        }
```